# Data prep for association rules in R - data frame to transaction

Tags: r, data-mining, apriori

My data is from a SQL database and is in a tabular form where I have multiple rows for a single transaction. Rather than just using the "product" field I wish to use all the other columns in the data frame.

My data is as per below:

```
transID <- c('1','1','2','3')
state <- c('TX','TX','CA','MA')
product <- c('Oranges','Banana','Fish','Cheese')
Month <- c('January','January','Febuary','March')
Place <- c('A','A','B','C')

transactions <- data.frame(transID,state,product,Month,Place)

transactions
  transID state product   Month Place
1       1    TX Oranges January     A
2       1    TX  Banana January     A
3       2    CA    Fish Febuary     B
4       3    MA  Cheese   March     C
```

Ideally, my data would look as follows:

```
1 (TX,Oranges,Banana,January,A)
2 (CA,Fish,Febuary,B)
3 (MA, Cheese, March,C)
```

What's is the best way to get this sort of data into a transactional format?

I've tried the following, but I just join row 1 and 2 together as a single transaction:

```
transactionData <- ddply(transactions,c("transID"),
                         function(df1) paste(df1$state,
                                             df1$product,
                                             df1$Month,
                                             df1$Place,
                                             collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You should provide intended output using R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little awkward to do since data.frames store factors.

```
library("arules")

# make all columns into items
df <- data.frame(
  id = transactions$transID, 
  items = factor(c(as.character(transactions$state),
    as.character(transactions$product), 
    as.character(transactions$Month), 
    as.character(transactions$Place))))

# remove duplicated state, month and place enties
df <- df[!duplicated(df),]

# this is from the manual page '? transactions'
trans <- as(split(df[,"items"], df[,"id"]), "transactions")    
inspect(trans)


    items                         transactionID
[1] {A,Banana,January,Oranges,TX} 1            
[2] {B,CA,Febuary,Fish}           2            
[3] {C,Cheese,MA,March}           3
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base solution:

```
stack(tapply(transactions[, -1], 
       transactions[, 1, drop = F],
       FUN = function(DF) {
         paste(unique(unlist(DF), use.names = F), collapse = ',')
       }))[, 2:1]

#  ind                      values
#1   1 TX,Oranges,Banana,January,A
#2   2           CA,Fish,Febuary,B
#3   3           MA,Cheese,March,C
```

The main part is the `tapply()` portion which splits by the `transID` and then unlists the rest of the `data.frame` and only keeps the unique values. Here's the output of just the `tapply()` call.

```
                            1                             2                             3 
"TX,Oranges,Banana,January,A"           "CA,Fish,Febuary,B"           "MA,Cheese,March,C"
```

The `stack()` and `[, 2:1]` is purely cosmetic to produce a nice `data.frame` that is ordered nicely.

Answer (score 0):

What about *reshaping* like this?

```
reshape(transactions,v.names = "product",timevar = "product",idvar = "state", direction = "wide")

transID state   Month Place product.Oranges product.Banana product.Fish product.Cheese
1       1    TX January     A         Oranges         Banana         <NA>           <NA>
3       2    CA Febuary     B            <NA>           <NA>         Fish           <NA>
4       3    MA   March     C            <NA>           <NA>         <NA>         Cheese
```